# seemingly simple question about polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I was recently looking at a problem that looked like this:

Let $x = rcos(t)$ and $y = rsin(t)$. Assuming that x is held constant, what is $\frac{\partial t}{\partial r}$?

Apparently the correct answer is $\frac{cot(t)}{r}$, but this is not what I am getting. I am just wondering what is wrong with my method.

I thought that an appropriate way to solve the problem would be to use the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial t}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial t}{\partial y}*\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$.

In this case, we have the equations t = arctan(y/x) and y=rsin(t), so

$\frac{\partial t}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{(1+(y/x)^2)}*2(y/x)*(1/x)$,   and
$\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} = sin(t)$.

Putting this all together, it can be simplified to cot(r)/r.

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial r} = 2*\frac{(sin(t))^2}{r}$

which is certainly not equivalent to $\frac{cot(t)}{r}$

Could someone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: I think your application of chain rule should be $$\frac{\partial t}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial t}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$

Comment: check out this [standard mathjax stuff](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @ chinny, thanks. But I don't see anything about derivatives on that page. @ angryavian, but dt/dx=0 because x is constant

Comment: You just said from your first comment that x evolves with time ($x = r \cos(t)$)

Comment: -1 this is you 5th question on this site, it's time to use LaTeX

Comment: @paul it was more for how you general use the equation environment than specifically your problem..I still till this day have to search google (awful term of phrase since I do not search google) but a freebie $\partial$ is "\partial" :).

Comment: @beidgeburnes, yes x depends on t but the codependency of t and r is such that x is constant

Comment: If you start by assuming that $x$ is a constant, where $x = r \,\cos\, t,$
then $t = \cos^{-1} \frac xr,$ which is a function of $r$ alone.
Then how do you distinguish the partial derivative $\frac {\partial t}{\partial r}$
from the total derivative $\frac {d t}{d r}?$

Answer (score 1):

Here it is easy to isolate the variables in which you are interested by noting that$$t=\arccos \frac xr$$

Now take the derivative with respect to $r$ noting that $x$ is constant to obtain $$-\frac x{r^2}\cdot -\frac {1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac {x^2}{r^2}\right)}}=\frac 1r\cdot\cos t\cdot\frac 1{\sin t}$$

Because you are taking the square root, this method requires checking that the sign comes out correctly.

Comment: +1 Neat. I went the other way and differentiated $r^2=x_0^2+y^2$ wrt $t$. Your way is neater and shorter.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why my approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You ask where you went wrong.
How about the step where you asserted that 
$\frac {\partial y}{\partial r} = \sin t?$
This assertion is true only if $\frac {\partial y}{\partial r}$ denotes how $y$ varies 
when you hold $t$ constant and allow $r$ to vary. 
But you have already assumed that $x$ is held constant, and since $x = r \,\cos\, t,$
it follows that $r$ is a function of $t.$
It is then impossible to vary $r$ while holding $t$ constant.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your response. I will try to use latex here. When I take into account what you said, I get $\frac{\partial t}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial t}{\partial y} * \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} = \frac{2y}{r^2}*(sin(t)-rcos(t)*\frac{\partial t}{\partial r})$. I am still having some trouble recovering the correct answer from this, but I should be able to get it from there. Thank you

Comment: OK, at least with clear notation, someone may be able to figure out how this works, but it may have to be someone whose topology is a little stronger than mine.